# Gitlab: filtering commits with Since attribute also gives older commits

Tags: php, git, curl, gitlab-api

I'm trying to only get the commits of this day. I'm using CURL to make the request. I've tried ISO 8601 and RFC3339 but neither yield the result I'm looking for.

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/ID/repository/commits",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Private-Token: PRIVATE-TOKEN",
                "since: 2018-09-03T00:00:00Z",
                "until: 2018-09-04T00:00:00Z"

            ),
        )); 

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        $commits =  $response;

        print_r($commits);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that in order for this to work, the since argument (and any other optional for that matter) needs to be in the url;

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/ID/repository/commits?since=2018-09-03T00:00:00Z&until=2018-09-04T00:00:00Z
```

instead of in the headers like I have been doing.